# Visual Studio виснет после установки WinDBG

Tags: visual-studio, отладка, windbg

Всем привет. Юзаю 19-ю студию, все приложения отлаживались нормально, понадобилось установить WinDBG из пакета Windows Kits, установил и после этого в студии перестала запускаться отладка, та что по F5, при этом запуск без отладки по Ctrl+F5 работает нормально.
Есть предположение, что WinDbg заменил каким-то образом собой студийный отладчик и из-за этого отладка перестала работать.
Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы студия юзала свой отладчик, а не тот, который был установлен. 
При этом WinDBG удалять не хочется. 
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сам спросил, сам отвечу.
Всё нормально, установка WinDbg тут ни при чём. Просто так звёзды сошлись.
В настройках студии, в Debugging - Symbols, поставил галку у Microsoft Symbol Servers.

А доступ туда закрыт, а студия пыталась вытянуть оттуда pdb-шники, но у неё ничего не получалось.
Из-за этого отладка не запускалась.

Comment: Можно как ответ пометить.